# Como obtengo el valor del select para mostrar una tabla con esos datos

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, combobox

Tengo realizado un CRUD y lo que quiero es filtrar según una ciudad, le asigne a un select todas la ciudades pero no puedo hacer que haga el filtro y me muestre la tabla con la selección del select. Cabe mencionar que lo estoy haciendo con Wordpress porque lo hice a manera de Plugin. Esto esta alojado en phpMyAdmin a manera de prueba.
En Conclusión lo que quiero es que si selecciono Buenos Aires en el select, me muestre la tabla con todos los usuarios que son de Buenos Aires.
Dejo el código a continuación:

```
                  <h2>Buscar un Registro por Ciudad</h2>
                  <br>
                  <?php
                  $resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
                  ?>
                  <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <select name="nombre_ciudad" id="nombre_ciudad">
                      <option value="">Seleccione una Ciudad</option>
                      <?php
                        foreach ($resultado as $ciudades) {
                          echo ("<option value='$ciudades->ciudad'>$ciudades->ciudad</option>)");
                        }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                    <a href='?page_id=17&buscar=$ciudades->ciudad'><button type='button'>Buscar</button></a>
                  </form>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <?php
                  if (isset($_GET['buscar'])) {
                    $buscar_ciudad = $_GET['buscar'];
                    $resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ciudad = '$buscar_ciudad'");
                    foreach ($resultado as $mostrar) {
                      $id = $mostrar->id;
                      $nombre = $mostrar->nombre;
                      $apellido = $mostrar->apellido;
                      $ciudad = $mostrar->ciudad;

                    echo "
                      <table>
                        <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Nombre</th>
                          <th>Apellido</th>
                          <th>Ciudad</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>$mostrar->id</td>
                          <td>$mostrar->nombre</td>
                          <td>$mostrar->apellido</td>
                          <td>$mostrar->ciudad</td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    ";
                  }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos opciones que te podrian valer.

1. En la tabla, por defecto cargas todos los usuarios, pero a cada uno de los  le asignas una class con el nombre de su ciudad o el id de su ciudad.
   Luego, simplemente con javascript detectas cuando el select cambia y ocultas todos los  de la tabla cuya class no sea igual al valor del select. De esa manera todos los tr que no sean de la ciudad seleccionada se ocultarán y solamente quedarán visibles los que pertenecen a la ciudad.
2. La tabla por defecto está vacia. Entonces, cuando el select cambia de valor, haces una llamada AJAX, en la cual mandas el valor de la ciudad seleccionada, a un archivo php el cual es el encargado de, a partir del parametro que le envias, obtener todos los usuarios que son de esas ciudad y devolverlos de vuelta a la funcion de javascript. Una vez la función recibe los datos, los insertas en la tabla.

Yo usaría la segunda opción ya que en la primera estás cargando datos innecesarios al solo querer obtener los usuarios de una ciudad en concreto. Con un número bajo de usuarios apenas notarás, pero conforme más usuarios tengas, más tiempo le costará obtener todos los datos.